# Facebook Graph API: get a Link title/caption/picture/description before posting to FB

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to show the automatically generated name, caption, description and picture from a URL before posting it to Facebook in my app.

This way the user can enter a URL and see what the defaults will be. If they wish to change the title/caption/picture/description before posting the link via the Graph API then they can.

Is there a way to do this through the Graph API, or would I need to build my own simple scraper and look for relevant meta tags myself?

Cheers,
Dave

--

Edit: Thanks @CBroe for the answer. Here's a dirty example in PHP for anyone else:

```
$url = 'http://google.com';
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array(
    'id' => $url,
    'scrape' => true,
));
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
print_r($data);
```

example output

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://www.google.com/
    [type] => website
    [title] => Google
    [image] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://www.google.com/images/google_favicon_128.png
                )

        )

    [description] => Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for.
    [updated_time] => 2014-04-02T10:41:44+0000
    [id] => 381702034999
)
```

works in app:
[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#selfhosted-update

Comment: OK, added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Updating Objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#selfhosted-update) in Facebook’s Open Graph documentation.

You can make a POST call to the API to get any URL scraped, and (on success) it will return you the *“all the information about the object that was scraped”* in JSON format.

Comment: excellent, have updated question with a quick example for anyone else. 

I'm not too sure what the facebook "Link Caption" is all about, I'll do a few more tests and see where the caption comes from.

Comment: The caption is displayed under the title of the link (if no caption is given, FB just displays the domain name of the link there) … at least that was the case with the old news feed layout, not sure if caption is present any more in the new layout. This caption is however specific to the post, it is not a property of the OG object.